# How to properly get contents of DLL file for PE parsing?

Tags: file, c++11, dll, io, portable-executable

I'm trying to get the RVA of a function in `kernel32.dll` which means I need to use the offsets to find different structures in the file until I can get the `IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY` structure. However I know a lot of methods and ways of getting the contents of files interpret and leave certain characters and stuff out which would make this a nearly impossible task. So I want to know the best way to go about getting the contents of a dll file to copy into a character array.

Update: For anyone interested I created a function for mapping the dll into memory.

```
void* GetFileImage(char path[])
{
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(path, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY, NULL);
    if(hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){return NULL;}

    HANDLE file_map = CreateFileMapping(hFile, NULL, PAGE_READONLY|SEC_IMAGE, 0, 0, "KernelMap");
    if(file_map == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){return NULL;}

    LPVOID file_image = MapViewOfFile(file_map, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0);
    if(file_image == 0){return NULL;}

    return file_image;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered mapping the .dll file into memory? CreateFileMapping... [This is an oldie, but a goodie.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways. Not that many multiple, though.

1.If you are trying to parse a system loaded file such as `kernel32.dll` which are loaded into memory on system startup, you can directly use `GetModuleHandle` to grab the loaded base address and start parsing through PE (assuming you are familiar with the PE structure and static/delay loading of dlls and its exports).

2.If the dll you are trying to parse is not one of the system loaded, you can load them using `LoadLibrary`, which will return you the loaded base address, thus enabling you to parse the PE.

3.You can also do `CreatFileMapping/MapViewOfFile` to map the dll in your own virtual memory to parse.

The msdn article suggested by @David Thomas will be of great help:: [Peering Inside the PE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx)